# copy an opencv::Mat to a Mat*

Tags: c++, opencv

Apologies if this is a stupid question, I am not the most experienced with using pointers in c++.

I am using openCv, and have a `cv::Mat` initialized as:

```
cv::Mat* frame;
```

I also have another Mat, filled with data initialized as:

```
cv::Mat frameRaw;
```

Obviously one is a pointer, and the other is not.

I need to copy the data from `frameRaw` into `frame`.

I have tried `*frame = frameRaw;` but it gives me an exception error.

How should I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: do you initialize your `frame` before use it?

Comment: Actually, it was commented out! works now, will update post. Thank you!

Comment: There is no need for this first syntax, can you just just replace it with the second? Usage of `new` is avoided in modern C++. Opencv follows that idiom and make things easier to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I had not initialized the `Mat` properly. Adding

`frame = new cv::Mat();`

fixes the issue.

Comment: You should avoid to use pointers to `Mat`, since you're likely to break internal reference counter. `Mat` objects basically are already _pointers_ to data

Answer (score 0):

See the code snippet, hope this will answer you:

```
Mat * f = new Mat(2,2,CV_32FC1);
    f->at<float>(0,0) = 1;
    f->at<float>(0,1) = 2;
    f->at<float>(1,0) = 3;
    f->at<float>(1,1) = 4;

    Mat ff;
    f->copyTo(ff);
    cout<<ff;
```